# How to find a text, copy it and insert in next line in a file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, scripting, xml

I'm trying to write a script that processes .xml file.  It has to find all lines with a `<title>` element, copy it, and paste in a next line after that found one, but also changing the element type. Here is an example.

Original:

> some text
>   `<title>`text 1`</title>`
>   some text
>   `<title>`text 2`</title>`
>   some text

And this is what I need to get:

> some text
>   `<title>`text 1`</title>`
>   `<description>`text 1`</description>`
>   some text
>   `<title>`text 2`</title>`
>   `<description>`text 2`</description>`
>   some text

Can it be done with sed or grep (or some other tool)?

Comment: why the second `<title>` line has `text 1` in the result? a typo?

Comment: yes, it was a typo, i've corrected it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed -E 's%<title>(.*)</title>%<title>\1</title>\n<desc>\1</desc>%g' file.xml` should do your homework.

To explain it a bit further:
`-E` parameter tells `sed` to use extended regular expressions, so you can use references. Replacing with sed is normally done in the form `s/search/replace/g`. As there are slashes in the search text we use `%` instead of `/` for sed to mark the parts, so we do not have to mask the slashes in the search text by a backslash. The rest is normal regex stuff, `\1` in the replace part references the snippet inside `(…)` in the search part.

Comment: This answer needs explanation.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I have not analyzed it yet, but it works!

Answer (score 3):

XML parsers/processors are the right tools for manipulating XML data.

[***xmlstarlet***](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) solution:

the exemplary `input.xml` content:

```
<root>
some text
<title>text 1</title>
some text
<title>text 2</title>
some text </root>
```

---

```
xmlstarlet ed -a '//title' -t elem -n 'description' -v '' input.xml \
 | xmlstarlet ed -u '//description' -x './preceding-sibling::title[1]/text()'
```

The output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
some text
<title>text 1</title><description>text 1</description>
some text
<title>text 2</title><description>text 2</description>
some text </root>
```

---

- `ed` - edit mode
- `-a` - append action
- `-u` - update action