# How can I move parts of one line of text to the next?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have fastq files from RNA-sequencing, in which I want to append part of each 1st line and an extra string of text to the next line.

These are the first 8 lines of my file:

```
@V300088128L1C001R0010000004#TCCTCGCATG/1
TTCAAGTAATCCAGGATAGGCT
+
FFDFFFFFFFFGFFFFFFFFFF
@V300088128L1C001R0010000019#CTGATATAGA/1
GTGGATCACTTGGCTCGGGA
+
F:FFFGF?FGGFFFFGFFEE
```

I want to copy the part between # and /1 from every line starting with @ to the end of the next line, followed by the string *AGTCGGAGGC*. The result should be:

```
@V300088128L1C001R0010000004#TCCTCGCATG/1
TTCAAGTAATCCAGGATAGGCTTCCTCGCATGAGTCGGAGGC
+
FFDFFFFFFFFGFFFFFFFFFF
@V300088128L1C001R0010000019#CTGATATAGA/1
GTGGATCACTTGGCTCGGGACTGATATAGAAGTCGGAGGC
+
F:FFFGF?FGGFFFFGFFEE
```

I checked [How to find a text, copy it and insert in next line in a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377819/how-to-find-a-text-copy-it-and-insert-in-next-line-in-a-file), but in that example a new line is inserted instead of appending to an existing line. I also tried the following, but I cannot figure out how to append/copy the searched string to the end of the (already existing) **next** line.

```
sed -E 's%#(.*)/%$\1AGTCGGAGGC%g' test3.txt > test3new.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
str != "" { $0 = $0 str "AGTCGGAGGC"; str="" }
match($0,"#.*/") { str = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2) }
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
@V300088128L1C001R0010000004#TCCTCGCATG/1
TTCAAGTAATCCAGGATAGGCTTCCTCGCATGAGTCGGAGGC
+
FFDFFFFFFFFGFFFFFFFFFF
@V300088128L1C001R0010000019#CTGATATAGA/1
GTGGATCACTTGGCTCGGGACTGATATAGAAGTCGGAGGC
+
F:FFFGF?FGGFFFFGFFEE
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -E '/^@/{ N; s/^(.*)#(.*)\/1(.*)/\1#\2\/1\3\2AGTCGGAGGC/; }' infile
```

if a line was start with `@` then read `N`ext line and capture 3 groups that later we weill use them to return back them based on the order requirements you have and append `2AGTCGGAGGC` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! It seems to work in the sense that the '2AGTCGGAGGC' is added to the next line, but instead of adding it to the end of the line, it is now replacing the characters at the beginning of that line.

Comment: @Leo I'm not sure what you are saying. the command does and produce output exactly what you showed as output according to the given input..

Comment: My best guess is the OP is saying they are seeing the effect of having DOS line endings, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a combination of awk and [seqkit](https://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/). The following command transforms the data into a tab-separated file that is easier to manipulate and then reverts it back to fastq.

```
seqkit fx2tab text.fq | awk '{ tag=$1; gsub(/(^.*#)|(\/1$)/,"" , tag); print $1 "\t" $2 tag "\t" $3 "FFFFFFFFFF"}' | seqkit tab2fx
```

You then have your desired output including an extension of the quality scores using phred+33 to maintain proper fastq formatting:

```
@V300088128L1C001R0010000004#TCCTCGCATG/1
TTCAAGTAATCCAGGATAGGCTTCCTCGCATG
+
FFDFFFFFFFFGFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@V300088128L1C001R0010000019#CTGATATAGA/1
GTGGATCACTTGGCTCGGGACTGATATAGA
+
F:FFFGF?FGGFFFFGFFEEFFFFFFFFFF
```

if your tags are of a variable size you can use the following variation based on code found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/86340/linux-command-to-repeat-a-string-n-times):

```
seqkit fx2tab text.fq | awk ' function str_repeat(s1, n1) {s2 = ""; for (n2 = 1; n2 <= n1; n2++) {s2 = s2 s1} return s2 }; {tag=$1; gsub(/(^.*#)|(\/1$)/,"" , tag);  print $1 "\t" $2 tag "\t" $3 str_repeat("F", length(tag)) }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `GNU sed` with extended regex mode `-E` we stick the next line to the @ line unless it's the last. Then we grab the text between # and /1 and also put a \n in the regex to ensure its from the @ line, and stick it to the end of pattern space.

```
sed -Ee '
  /@/{$!N;}
  s|#(.*)/1.*\n.*|&\1AGTCGGAGGC|
' file
```